# Search not working properly with datagridview and textboxes

Tags: c#

I would like to search for a record through textbox via save button and display searched data in other textboxes and i want to see the searched row in datagrid selected. I managed to solve both codes. but i couldn't mix 2 code and make it 1. sorry for my bad english anyways here are my two codes

```
//shows searched row in datagridview but does not show in textboxes             
SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from cabphase1 where CODENO='"+txtTNo.Text+"'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        sqlCon.Close();


       //2nd code: Shows in textbox but not in datagridview
       try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from cabphase1 where CODENO = '" + txtCODENOAT.Text + "'", sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (dr.Read())
            {
                txtDNAMEAT.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                txtLNOAT.Text = dr[1].ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Taxi CODENO - Eg: 31", "FAILED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }


            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Searching Data" , "Dispatch", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: The record you are searching is already available in GridView and you want to highlight that record in the GridView?

Comment: Yes @ChetanRanpariya as well as like my code display in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to execute the same query against the database. You can use the data retrieved in the first operation to display in the text boxes too.

Also you should not be using string concatenation to generate SQL queries in the code. That is prone to SQL injection. Parameterized queries are highly recommended to protect from SQL injection.

Following code uses the parameterized query.

```
//shows searched row in datagridview but does not show in textboxes             
SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from cabphase1 where CODENO = @codeno";
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@codeno", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
parameter.Value = txtTNo.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
sqlCon.Close();

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
    
    txtDNAMEAT.Text = row[0].ToString();
    txtLNOAT.Text = row[1].ToString();
}
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue.